# KnockoutJS / jQuery UI Sortable Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dom, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm attempting to use KnockoutJS and jQuery UI Sortable together.  I know this has been done before (particularly, [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable)), but my use case has some pretty specific behavior and I'm hoping to avoid trying to make the switch.

Anyway, the problem is pretty straightforward - after moving a DOM element with jQuery UI Sortable, Knockout behaves strangely when removing the observableArray element bound to that DOM element.  It will fail to remove the moved element, and if the element that fell into the moved element's place is removed, it will remove both that and the originally moved element. Hard to put into words, but demonstrated by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joelhoward/vgrTY/3/).

The problem seems actually take place in the following block in knockout-2.1.0.js:

```
function fixUpVirtualElements(contiguousNodeArray) {
    // Ensures that contiguousNodeArray really *is* an array of contiguous siblings, even if some of the interior
    // ones have changed since your array was first built (e.g., because your array contains virtual elements, and
    // their virtual children changed when binding was applied to them).
    // This is needed so that we can reliably remove or update the nodes corresponding to a given array item

    if (contiguousNodeArray.length > 2) {
        // Build up the actual new contiguous node set
        var current = contiguousNodeArray[0], last = contiguousNodeArray[contiguousNodeArray.length - 1], newContiguousSet = [current];
        while (current !== last) {
            current = current.nextSibling;
            if (!current) // Won't happen, except if the developer has manually removed some DOM elements (then we're in an undefined scenario)
                return;
            newContiguousSet.push(current);
        }

        // ... then mutate the input array to match this.
        // (The following line replaces the contents of contiguousNodeArray with newContiguousSet)
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(contiguousNodeArray, [0, contiguousNodeArray.length].concat(newContiguousSet));
    }
}
```

This call is adding the moved DOM element to the list of elements to be removed when the shifted element is removed.

So an open call to any jQuery UI / Knockoutjs geniuses - is there a way to resolve this conflict, or do I need to do something entirely different to make these tools play nicely together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "best" solution is to remove the element from DOM and change its position in KO. You can do this in the `stop` event of the sortable. http://jsfiddle.net/vgrTY/4/

I went ahead and changed your `array-contents` text to a computed as well so it'll properly display.